# first order non-linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the first order non-linear ODE,

$$\frac{dX}{dt} = -AX^2$$

for $-\mathrm{del}(X)$ or $-(X1-X0)$

My classmate said the answer is $\dfrac{AX^2\mathrm{del}(t)}{1+AX\mathrm{del}(t)}$ where $\mathrm{del}(t)$ is (t1-t0), but I cant seem to get this answer.

After integrating I get: $X(t) = \dfrac{1}{A*t + c1} $
solving for $c1, c1= \dfrac{1-XAt}{X}$
but i dont know where to go from there.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This equation can be solved by a method called separation of variables, meaning move the $X$'s to one side of the equation, and everything else to the opposite side.  So in this case, you can rearrange the equation to be $\frac{X'}{-AX^2} = 1$.  The left side can now be seen as $((AX)^{-1})'$, and so integrating both sides from $t_0$ to $t$ gets you $(AX)^{-1} = t - t_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\int \dfrac{dx}{x^2} = \int -a dt$$

This results in:

$$-\dfrac{1}{x} = -at + c$$

This simplifies to:

$$x(t) = \dfrac{1}{at + c}$$

Were you given an initial condition?