# first orderr non linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came along this first order non linear ODE, and cannot solve it.

$$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{-b}{(vt)^2}+k$$ (where b and k are constants)

The question asked to express v as a function of t.

Thank you very much, any help is welcome!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Just because the similiar question exists here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467767/first-order-non-linear-ode it doesn't mean that u should change the title that way !!!

Answer (score 0):

Assume $b\neq0$ and $k\neq0$ for the key case:

Hint:

Approach $1$:

$\dfrac{dv}{dt}=-\dfrac{b}{(vt)^2}+k$

$\dfrac{dv}{dt}-k=-\dfrac{b}{v^2t^2}$

$\dfrac{d(v-kt)}{dt}=-\dfrac{b}{v^2t^2}$

Let $x=v-kt$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=-\dfrac{b}{(x+kt)^2t^2}$

$\dfrac{dt}{dx}=-\dfrac{k^2t^4+2kxt^3+x^2t^2}{b}$

This belongs to a "Chini-like" equation.

Approach $2$:

Let $x=vt$ ,

Then $v=\dfrac{x}{t}$

$\dfrac{dv}{dt}=\dfrac{1}{t}\dfrac{dx}{dt}-\dfrac{x}{t^2}$

$\therefore\dfrac{1}{t}\dfrac{dx}{dt}-\dfrac{x}{t^2}=-\dfrac{b}{x^2}+k$

$\dfrac{1}{t}\dfrac{dx}{dt}=k-\dfrac{b}{x^2}+\dfrac{x}{t^2}$

$\dfrac{1}{t}\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\dfrac{(kx^2-b)t^2+x^3}{x^2t^2}$

$((kx^2-b)t^2+x^3)\dfrac{dt}{dx}=x^2t$

Let $u=\dfrac{1}{t^2}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dx}=-\dfrac{2}{t^3}\dfrac{dt}{dx}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{((kx^2-b)t^2+x^3)t^3}{2}\dfrac{du}{dx}=x^2t$

$\left(\dfrac{1}{t^2}+\dfrac{k}{x}-\dfrac{b}{x^3}\right)\dfrac{du}{dx}=-\dfrac{2}{xt^4}$

$\left(u+\dfrac{k}{x}-\dfrac{b}{x^3}\right)\dfrac{du}{dx}=-\dfrac{2u^2}{x}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $v=u+\dfrac{k}{x}-\dfrac{b}{x^3}$ ,

Then $u=v-\dfrac{k}{x}+\dfrac{b}{x^3}$

$\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{dv}{dx}+\dfrac{k}{x^2}-\dfrac{3b}{x^4}$

$\therefore v\left(\dfrac{dv}{dx}+\dfrac{k}{x^2}-\dfrac{3b}{x^4}\right)=-\dfrac{2}{x}\left(v-\dfrac{k}{x}+\dfrac{b}{x^3}\right)^2$

$v\dfrac{dv}{dx}+\left(\dfrac{k}{x^2}-\dfrac{3b}{x^4}\right)v=-\dfrac{2}{x}\left(v^2-\left(\dfrac{2k}{x}-\dfrac{2b}{x^3}\right)v+\dfrac{(kx^2-b)^2}{x^6}\right)$

$v\dfrac{dv}{dx}+\left(\dfrac{k}{x^2}-\dfrac{3b}{x^4}\right)v=-\dfrac{2v^2}{x}+\left(\dfrac{4k}{x^2}-\dfrac{4b}{x^4}\right)v-\dfrac{2(kx^2-b)^2}{x^7}$

$v\dfrac{dv}{dx}=-\dfrac{2v^2}{x}+\left(\dfrac{3k}{x^2}-\dfrac{b}{x^4}\right)v-\dfrac{2(kx^2-b)^2}{x^7}$

Let $v=\dfrac{w}{x^2}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dv}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{x^2}\dfrac{dw}{dx}-\dfrac{2w}{x^3}$

$\therefore\dfrac{w}{x^2}\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2}\dfrac{dw}{dx}-\dfrac{2w}{x^3}\right)=-\dfrac{2w^2}{x^5}+\left(\dfrac{3k}{x^2}-\dfrac{b}{x^4}\right)\dfrac{w}{x^2}-\dfrac{2(kx^2-b)^2}{x^7}$

$\dfrac{w}{x^4}\dfrac{dw}{dx}-\dfrac{2w^2}{x^5}=-\dfrac{2w^2}{x^5}+\left(\dfrac{3k}{x^2}-\dfrac{b}{x^4}\right)\dfrac{w}{x^2}-\dfrac{2(kx^2-b)^2}{x^7}$

$\dfrac{w}{x^4}\dfrac{dw}{dx}=\left(\dfrac{3k}{x^2}-\dfrac{b}{x^4}\right)\dfrac{w}{x^2}-\dfrac{2(kx^2-b)^2}{x^7}$

$w\dfrac{dw}{dx}=\left(3k-\dfrac{b}{x^2}\right)w-\dfrac{2(kx^2-b)^2}{x^3}$